# Django: Filter against a value of another row

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I'm having a model `Foo` with with a `value` field.

```py
# models.py

class Foo(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField()
```

Now I want to filter all `Foo` instances that have a greater `value` than the `Foo` object with a specific knwon id.

```py
pk = 10
obj = Foo.objects.get(pk=pk)
qs = Foo.objects.filter(value__gte=obj.value)
```

The question is can I somehow combine the two db queries above into one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a subquery, although I am not sure that this makes it very readable:

```
Foo.objects.filter(
    value__gte=Foo.objects.filter(pk=10).values('value')
)
```

This will result in a query that looks like:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE foo.value >= (
    SELECT U0.value
    FROM foo AS U0
    WHERE id = 10
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I agree it's not very readable, but it really solves my specific use case

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can, short of using raw SQL (which I'm not competent to write). Having said that, I fully expect somebody to show me that I'm wrong.

What I would say, is that it's not often worth making code less clear to save a single DB query. Especially the simplest possible one, of retrieving one object by its id. (You could reduce load on the database connection and Django server  by changing it to a [values_list query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#values_list), and that would not make the code obscure, just longer).

You can use F [(link)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters) to filter by comparing one field in an object to another field in the same or a related object, but that's not the case here.